# Assembler - EQU calculate what?

Tags: assembly, x86

In the next code:

```
section .data
    sa db ’abxdefghxl’,0
    la  EQU $ - sa
    sb db ’abcdexghil’,0
section .text
```

As I saw in my program, when I do mov ecx, la - then I got the number 11 in ECX. 
I didn't understand why - the number of `abxdefghxl` is not 10. We also count the 0?

Comment: Of course, it takes the difference in position between "here" and `sa`, so it counts *everything* in between.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume `sa` to start at `0x400`. You have defined 10 ( `abxdefghxl` ) plus 1 ( `0` at the end ) And hence `la` wwould start at `0x40B`. $ represents the current instruction/directive address. Hence `$-sa` = `0xB` or `11`

Answer (score 1):

$ represents the current position. And since the current position is after the complete declaration of "sa", the expression $-sa is 11. Remember that in assembly there is no thing like a "string" data type, "sa" is just a collection of bytes.

Comment: `$-sa` would be 11 as he has one additional zero at the end of the string.

Comment: @PavanManjunath: Of course, it was my intent to type 11. Thanks I've corrected it now.